# When the controller becomes the second node (id 2) zookeeper and Kafka not working

Tags: apache-kafka, cluster-computing, apache-zookeeper, kafka-cluster

we have a Kafka cluster with three nodes. We have a weird problem. When the controller becomes the second node (id 2) zookeeper and Kafka not working.

zookeeper config :

```
maxClientCnxns=50
tickTime=2000
initLimit=10
syncLimit=5
dataDir=/var/lib/zookeeper
clientPort=2181
server.1=x.x.x.x:2888:3888
server.2=x.x.x.x:2888:3888
server.3=x.x.x.x:2888:3888
```

kafka config :

```
broker.id=2
delete.topic.enable=true
advertised.listeners=PLAINTEXT://x.x.x.x:9092
num.network.threads=16
num.io.threads=16
socket.send.buffer.bytes=102400
socket.receive.buffer.bytes=102400
socket.request.max.bytes=104857600
log.dirs=/kafka-logs
num.partitions=1
num.recovery.threads.per.data.dir=1
offsets.topic.replication.factor=1
transaction.state.log.replication.factor=1
transaction.state.log.min.isr=1
log.retention.hours=48
log.segment.bytes=1073741824
log.retention.check.interval.ms=300000
zookeeper.connect=x.x.x.x:2181,x.x.x.x:2181,x.x.x.x:2181/kafka
zookeeper.connection.timeout.ms=6000
group.initial.rebalance.delay.ms=0
auto.create.topics.enable=false
leader.imbalance.check.interval.seconds=60
auto.leader.rebalance.enable=false
```

Kafka error:

```
[2019-07-07 09:28:30,201] INFO [Partition partition-name-11 broker=1] Shrinking ISR from 1,2 to 1 (kafka.cluster.Partition)
[2019-07-07 09:28:30,202] INFO [Partition partition-name-11 broker=1] Cached zkVersion [1208] not equal to that in zookeeper, skip updating ISR (kafka.cluster.Partition)

[2019-07-07 09:28:30,328] INFO [ReplicaFetcher replicaId=1, leaderId=3, fetcherId=0] Remote broker is not the leader for partition partition-name-4, which could indicate that the partition is being moved (kafka.server.ReplicaFetcherThread)


[2019-07-07 09:28:03,088] WARN [LeaderEpochCache partition-name-8] New epoch entry EpochEntry(epoch=1670, startOffset=0) caused truncation of conflicting entries ListBuffer(EpochEntry(epoch=1668, startOffset=0)). Cache now contains 1 entries. (kafka.server.epoch.LeaderEpochFileCache)
[2019-07-07 09:28:03,088] INFO [Partition partition-name-11 broker=1] Cached zkVersion [2920] not equal to that in zookeeper, skip updating ISR (kafka.cluster.Partition)

[2019-07-07 10:21:59,386] INFO [Partition partition-name-4 broker=2] partition-name-4 starts at Leader Epoch 1105 from offset 0. Previous Leader Epoch was: 1104 (kafka.cluster.Partition)
```

and zookeeper error:

```
2019-07-07 10:22:20,314 [myid:2] - INFO  [ProcessThread(sid:2 cport:-1)::PrepRequestProcessor@653] - Got user-level KeeperException when processing sessionid:0x1013041373b0073 type:setData cxid:0x5732 zxid:0x4e0011f115 txntype:-1 reqpath:n/a Error Path:/kafka/brokers/topics/partition-name/partitions/7/state Error:KeeperErrorCode = BadVersion for /kafka/brokers/topics/partition-name/partitions/7/state
```

Comment: What's your Kafka version?

Comment: "kafka_2.11.2.0.1" And "Zookeeper-3.4.12"

Comment: what's difference between these config files,when zookeeper is coordinator base.?? @cricket_007

Comment: Well, `Cached zkVersion` in the logs can be traced to this issue - https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-7165 and was fixed in Kafka 2.2.0